# ile "manage.py", line 9, in <module> from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

Tags: python, django, database

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

import os
import sys

if **name** == "**main**":
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "api.settings")

```
from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

~

anyone can explane this code. while ı have trying to run this code with "`python manage.py makemigrations`" its gives an error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EiGow.png)

but all modules in requrement.txt succsessfully loaded before.

Comment: have you activated the environment?

Answer (score 0):

It might  be possible that django package is not installed or installed properly.

- Create a virtual environment.

  python3 -m venv your_venv_name
- Activate virtual environment.

  source your_venv_name/bin/activate
- Install requirements.txt

  pip install -r requirements.txt
- Install Django package

  pip install Django